# Can we connect multiple accounts of a user for the same provider using hybridAuth?

Tags: php, hybridauth

Can we connect multiple account of user of same provider using hybridauth? For example, user A has two Facebook accounts:

1. Personal
2. Office

I want to allow user to save his both profile to my website using hybridAuth.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that. Hybrid Auth only facilitates the connection. It starts it, runs the user through it and returns the data for to your website. So if at the end of the whole process you have a code that links the received information to the user on your site, the user just needs to run through the process again and login into the other account for it to be associated with their account on your page (given that your linkage is not provider specific).